# Installing PDO and other PHP extensions for magento

Tags: apache-2.2, php, magento, pdo, mcrypt

I have a server and i was using php files on it. For some reason i had to reinstall apache on it. My files and my SQL database is still there.

Now after fresh installation of Apache, when i run my php website i get PDO NOT INSTALLED error.

So if now i install "PDO, PDO_MySQL, simplexml, mcrypt, hash, GD, DOM, iconv, curl"
will any of them effect my data?

If so is there anyway i can skip the headache of taking backup of both files and SQL?

Comment: Short answer: no. It just affects your PHP core. Not your database nor  file

Comment: so i should simple go ahead and install php-pdo using yum install php-pdo?

Comment: yup. It shouldn't affect your files

Comment: Using yum install php-pdo gives "No package php-pdo available." what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Installation of PHP modules is not related at all with your databases or other data. Depending on your server install the modules using YUM or APT, and it should work just fine. You may need to activate any module in php.ini if there are not activated by default. The restart of apache may be required.